# Compute the length of a parametric curve.

Tags: calculus, parametric, curves

It seems like I am not using the good process to compute the length of a given parametric curve. I am not sure if it's inside my calculations or if the steps I use are not correct.

The equation of the curve is : 
$$
\vec{r}(t) = \sqrt{2}t\space\vec{i}+e^t\space\vec{j}+ e^{-t}\space\vec{k}, \space t = [0,1]
$$

I am first starting by finding the derivative.
$$
\vec{r}\space'(t) = \sqrt{2} \space \vec{i} + e^t \vec{j} - e^{-t} \vec{k}, \space t = [0,1]
$$

After, I am calculating the magnitude of the last vector.

$$
||\vec{r}\space'(t)|| = \sqrt{2(1+e^{t^2})},\space t = [0,1]
$$

Finally, with

$$
L=\int_0^1 \sqrt{2(1+e^{t^2})}\;dt\\
$$

I find,

$$
L = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2\sqrt{1+e}}-\frac{1}{2}
$$

Which is a negative result and then impossible. Are my calculations wrong or my process not right?

P.S.: I am new to the site and it is my first post. Thus, feedbacks on the quality of the post can be helpful.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The magnitude is not quite right. When you square and add, you should get $\sqrt{e^{2t}+2+e^{-2t}}$, which is $e^t+e^{-t}$. Now integration is easy.

Comment: Yes. I have mistaken the $(e^t)^2$. Basic exponent rule $a^m\space x\space a^n = a^{m\space+\space n}$. Thank you.

Comment: You are welcome. Textbook arclength questions are usually set up so that by "magic" the integration is easy.  Your integration of the wrong expression was not correct. In fact that function almost certainly does not have an antiderivative expressible in terms of elementary functions.

Comment: You are right. I did the calculation quickly and made a big mistake of using $\sqrt{1+e^{t^2}}$ as $u$ but I did not consider $dt$. Thank you very much.

Comment: I am not sure how did you manage to get $e^t\space+\space e^{-t}$ from $\sqrt{e^{2t}\space+2+e^{-2t}}$

Comment: Let's do it backwards, by expanding $(e^t+e^{-t})^2$ using the usual expansion for $(x+y)^2$. We get $e^{2t}+2e^te^{-t}+e^{-2t}$. But the middle term $2e^te^{-t}$ is equal to $2$.

Comment: Well, this is quite interesting. I did not see this transformation before. Given the fact that $e$ is a constant and whatever constant will fit, this is useful for simplification. Thank you again.

Comment: This kind of middle term "cancellation" comes up surprisingly often.

Comment: That proves that I am a beginner ! I will keep this advice in mind for future problems !